# Referencing figures when compiling with pdfLaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, pdftex, captions

I had a problem in referencing figures, which now I solved, thanks to an [old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27888/having-trouble-cross-referencing-figures) by Werner.

To be precise, in my case the reference was working properly (the hyperlink was pointing to the correct figure), but I couldn't manage to substitute the double question mark with the correct figure number.

Why does the relative placement of `\label` and `\caption` matter, shouldn't the double compilation of the LaTeX code suffice? Is there a technical reason for this behaviour?
I noticed that it occurs only when compiling with pdfLaTeX, not with LaTeX.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The behaviour is same in latex and pdflatex. `\label` labels "the current referencable value" and that is set typically by headings and captions. If you use `\label` before `\caption` it is not an error, it is just that at that point the current referencable value is typically the section counter

Comment: Think of it like a stack of referencable pointers and every `\chapter`, `\caption`, etc. commands pushes new pointer and every `\end{<float>}` rejects all `\caption` pointers. The `\label` command then reads and stores value of pointer that is, at this time, on top of this stack no matter what happens afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry for the duplicate question!
(Incidentally, I was already using the Search function: that's how I found the question I linked above!)