# Not displaying 'Figure' cross reference

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I'm using ShareLatex and I'm trying to add a cross reference of a figure, but the result of the `\ref{fig:sampe}` only displays the number of the image and does not follow the format 'Figure 1' for example. I've tried with `figure` and `subfigures` and the result is the same.

Currently I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

And also added the following lines:

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

I've already checked the following posts [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27888/having-trouble-cross-referencing-figures) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19651/reference-to-a-figure-uses-the-sections-number). 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've added compilable code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}


\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=none,
    urldate=edtf,
    date=edtf,
    seconds=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Some text, here it would have to appear the first reference \cref{fig:test1} , here it would have to appear the seconds reference \cref{fig:nav01_welcome}.

\begin{figure}[H] 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav01_welcome.png}
  \caption{Pantalla de bienvenida}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}  


\begin{figure}  
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav01_welcome.png}
        \caption{Arabic numerals}\label{fig:1a}     
        \label{fig:nav01_welcome}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav02_welcome.png}
        \caption{Arabic numerals}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Capital Roman numerals}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried using `\cref{<key>}`? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post to add the comilable code sample where the problem I'm facing can be reproduced. But anyway thanks @Troy, \cref{<key>} did the trick.

Comment: How is this compilable? There is no `documentclass` line. You claimed to load package `cleveref` but the example doesn't show that either.

Comment: Also, *visitado en* does not seem to be english. Why are you confusing yourself and others by saying so?

Comment: Sorry, I seems that there was a mistake while editing the code. Now it's ok.

Comment: `./images/navigation/nav02_welcome.png` doesn't work for anyone other than you. It would be better if you use `example-image` (which is in tex distributions for this reason) and check that the issue still occurs with the example in that form. Or since your question is not about the image, replace `\includegraphics` by `IMAGE HERE` or anything else.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. `\ref{label}`  is supposed to only output the number. On the other hand,   `\cref{label}`  adds the kind of counter you are referring to. And you already use that. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is well if you load the `cleveref` package *last* -- and if you use `\cref` instead of `\ref`.

Two additional suggestions: Don't provide more than one `\label` per `\caption`. And, the three `\centering` instructions in the second `figure` environment may be eliminated if you replace `\quad` with `\hfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo,spanish]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,babel,caption,subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
%\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

% Load "cleveref" last:
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Here's the first cross-reference: \cref{fig:test}. 

Here's the second cross-reference: \cref{fig:2a}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav01_welcome.png}
   \caption{Pantalla de bienvenida}
   \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}  

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav01_welcome.png}
    \caption{Arabic numerals}\label{fig:2a}     
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./images/navigation/nav02_welcome.png}
    \caption{Arabic numerals}\label{fig:2b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Capital Roman numerals}\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```